# How to stop launching activity multiple times

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm launching Google Maps in Android from a particular view in my app layout like this:

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
view.getContext().startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Once I'm done with the maps and return to my app, the maps app is being launched again when I click anywhere (not just that particular view) on my app.

How do I stop this from happening?
I need maps to launch only when a particular view is displayed.

Comment: Where you have added those two lines of code ?? share the class please

Answer (score 0):

Try to call finish(); and return(); after you are starting the intent

something like this

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION.VIEW,loaction);
view.getContext().startActivity(mapIntent);
finish();
return;
```

Comment: Just curious. Without knowing where in the OP`s code `startActivity()` is being called or how the app UX is intended, how could you possibly suggest to call `finish()`?